# Jenkins - Active choice reactive reference parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

Greetings!
I am novice to Jenkins and Groovy. I have a below usecase where I am not able to print the user input values and pass the same to shell script. Could somebody share me your inputs on how to get the input values stored in a variable and print the same in the execute shell.

Appreciate your help on this!

```html
Here is the script
============================================================================
Active Choices Parameter:
      Name   DB_DUMP_TYPE
      Script    (.) Groovy Script
                     
                     Script
                          Groovy Script     return[
                                                       'EXPDB'
                                                       'IMPDB'                                                     

                                  Fallback Script
                                       Groovy Script    return["error"]
                           
                     Choice Type [Single Select]


Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter
               Name   (leave blank, dont give any thing here)
            Script (.) Groovy script 

if(DB_DUMP_TYPE.equals("IMPDB")){
def FullHTML = """
<label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_DUMP_TYPE</label>
<input name='DB_DUMP_TYPE' type='text'> </input> <br>
<label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_DUMP</label>
<input name='DB_DUMP' type='text'> </input> 
"""
return FullHTML    }

if(DB_DUMP_TYPE.equals("EXPDB")){
def FullHTML = """
<label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_WALLET</label>
<input name='DB_WALLET' type='text'> </input> <br>
<label style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DW_SCHEMA</label>
<input name='DW_SCHEMA' type='text'> </input> 
"""
return FullHTML    }

Fallback Script
   Groovy Script return["script error"]


Referenced Parameters DB_DUMP_TYPE
```

Comment: Did you set 'Choice Type' of the second one to 'Formatted HTML'?

Comment: yes. i selected the Choice Type as 'Formatted Html'

Comment: Could somebody provide solution to this query?

Answer (score 1):

I tried several ways with this problem.

First, you should set input 'name' tag as "value" to pass it as parameter value.

```
if(DB_DUMP_TYPE.equals("IMPDB")) {
  def FullHTML = """
    <label for="DB_DUMP_TYPE" style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_DUMP_TYPE</label>
      <input id="DB_DUMP_TYPE" type='text' name="value"><br>
    <label for="DB_DUMP" style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_DUMP</label>
      <input id="DB_DUMP" type='text' name="value"> 
  """
  return FullHTML
}

if(DB_DUMP_TYPE.equals("EXPDB")) {
  def FullHTML = """
    <label for="DB_WALLET" style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_WALLET</label>
      <input id="DB_WALLET" type='text' name="value"><br>
    <label for="DB_SCHEMA" style="left: 22% position: absolute;">DB_SCHEMA</label>
      <input id="DB_SCHEMA" type='text' name="value">
  """
  return FullHTML
}
```

This script should work. But it will pass the input values as a CSV string.
(e.g. - if you typed `DB_WALLET = 'ABC'` and `DB_SCHEMA = 'DEF'`, it will pass `'ABC','DEF'` array with blank name variable)

So you have to set parameters **independently**.
(so in this case, you have to set 4 reference parameters)
(it seems that we can't set parameter name dynamically with this plugin..)

---

Below is the HTML source code of `Build with Parameters` page.
The `script we have written` goes after `parameter name` has been set, so we can't set `parameter name` dynamically.
(or maybe, there's some other way to pass `parameter name`..)

[image: parameter html code]